# Error Insert Base de datos con php

Tags: php, php5

Buenas

Estoy intentando hacer un insert a una base de datos desde php. No me da ningún fallo aparente pero no es capaz de insertar nuevas filas en la tabla.
Este es el codigo. data2.php

```
if($_POST['add'] == 1) {
    echo "Add";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (id, name, description, img, show) VALUES (:id, :name, :description, :img, :show)";
    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $imgfile="http://placehold.it/140x120/";
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    echo "Add";
    if ($image){
        echo "imagen";
        $extension = getExtension($image);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
            echo "Invalid file type";
        } else {
            /*$size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024) {
                echo "File size error";
            } else {
                $temp=resizeImage($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],140,120);*/
                $filename = $url.".".$extension;
                $imgfile="./assets/img/noticias/".$filename;
                imagejpeg ( $temp, $imgfile );

        }
    }
    $id=NULL;
    //echo "fueraimagen";
    if ($_POST['enabled'] == "on") {
        $show = 1;
    } else {
        $show = 0;
    }

        $query->execute( array( 
                            ':id'=>$id,
                            ':name'=>$_POST['name'],
                            ':description'=>$_POST['description'],
                            ':img'=>$imgfile,
                            ':show'=>$show ) );
    echo "query";
    foreach($db->query ("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM noticias") as $row) {
        $id=$row['id'];
    }
    echo ($id);
    //echo ($form_data['convs']);
    header('Location: panel.php');

}
```

Esta es la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi envio información desde el html, panel.php

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#añadirCurso">Añadir Noticia</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="añadirCurso" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" action="data2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" id="add" value="1">   
    <input type="hidden" name="mod" id="mod" value="0">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Noticia</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Nombre de la noticia">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Descripción</label>
          <textarea class="form-control rte-zone" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Descripción de la noticia" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="image">Imagen</label>
          <input type="file" id="image" name="image">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">  
          <input type="checkbox" id="enabled" name="enabled" checked><label for="enabled">Mostrar noticia</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: No sé si has leído la advertencia que te hace PHPMyAdmin con respecto a la columna `show`, debes cambiar su nombre ya que es una palabra reservada. Luego, ¿guardas el archivo de imagen en un campo del tipo `varchar`? ¿No debería ser del tipo [`BLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)?  Cambia eso, intenta de nuevo y si falla revisa el `error_log`, posteando en la pregunta el mensaje que obtienes.

Comment: @A.Cedano tu la tienes mas clara con mysql que yo, pero ID no debería ser un autonumerico de algún tipo?

Comment: En general sí @gbianchi, aunque no es obligatorio. Es muy probable que en este caso sí debería ser un autonumérico.

Comment: @A.Cedano es que puede que su error también este ahí.. porque en ningún caso sabe cual es el ultimo id, como para agregar el que sigue...